# springmvc app URL works locally but not on server

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j, debian

I have a simple springmvc app that works when i deploy it in my local instance of tomcat as a war. After deploying I goto http://localhost:8080/Test works.

When I deploy the same instance in the server (using debian) in the same version of tomcat http://remote:8080/Test it gives 404

There is literally no change. I am using the annotated version of the springmvc.

My pom.xml looks like following:

> <build>
>           <finalName>TestResults</finalName>
>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>   <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee&quot; xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd&quot; xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd&quot; id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

</web-app>

Any idea how to debug? 
I have added log4j but I didnt see even the request for my app coming through?

The remote host was running old (not sure which) version of debian was upgraded recently to 7.0. Thats when it stopped working

There is also no logging present.

I have set my logging.properties set to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/app.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.DEBUG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
#outputs to Tomcat home
log4j.appender.DEBUG.File=${catalina.home}/logs/tomcat-debug.log
log4j.appender.DEBUG.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.DEBUG.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.DEBUG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DEBUG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Is your war deployed successfully and there is no startup error in tomcat logs?

Comment: There are no errors as far as i could tell when the app is deployed

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that there are no log files created even though i have set to ALL